# Permissions for git project when using on remote server

Tags: git, permissions, file-permissions, user-permissions

These are the commands that I've ran on my server:

```
$ whoami
git

$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 git  git  4096 Jan 16 05:48 git

$ ls -l git/
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 7 git git 4096 Jan 16 05:55 tpro.git
```

Then on my local machine:

```
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/t.git
```

Then
But when I want to push into the server from my local machine I have the following error:

```
$ git push -u origin master 
fatal: '/opt/git/t.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `tpro.git` but are trying to access `t.git`.

Make sure the path exists.
And make sure `tpro.git` is indeed in `/opt/git` (not `/home/git`)

Then try:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/tpro.git, 
git push -u origin master
```

That will ensure `master` will be pushing to `origin/master` every time, with a simple `git push`.

Comment: It refrence me to `fatal: '/opt/git/t.git' does not appear to be a git repository` even I use tpro.git

Comment: @MLSC First, does `/opt/git/tpro.git` on your server?

Comment: Yes ofcourse... the command ` ls -l git/` is ran on /opt directory

Comment: @MLSC OK (you didn't include `pwd` in your question, so I had to ask ;) ). Second, can you do a `ssh git@gitserver ls /opt/git/tpro.git`?

Comment: Yes I have :`branches
config
description
HEAD
hooks
info
objects
refs
`

Comment: @MLSC looks good! Now: in your local repo, type `git remote set-upstream origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/tpro.git`, and try again this time with a `git push -u origin master`. (not just `git push`)

Comment: @MLSC What version of git are you using on your local Windows PC?

Comment: @MLSC Sorry, I meant git remote `set-url`, not `set-upstream`